# How to change image in picturebox C#

Tags: c#, picturebox

I need to change the image by clicking on pictureBox, but when I click it again I can't return former picture

Here is my code:

```
private void PictureBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (pictureBox.Image == Properties.Resources.openeye)
        pictureBox.Image = Properties.Resources.closeeye;
    else
        pictureBox.Image = Properties.Resources.openeye;
}
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: images don't have equality tests like that.  You need to use your own variable to check the active image being used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example that demonstrates it with two images. One of an "x" another of an "o".

As you can see, the form has two instance variables `x` and `o` to store each of the `Image` objects. There is another flag field called `isX` which the `ClickHandle` event handler uses to check which image is currently displayed and switch to the other image, the event handler then toggles the `isX` field so the next click responds properly.

```
public void Main(string[] args)
{
    var f1 = new Form1(); // form instance that holds the PictureBox

    Task.Run(() => Application.Run(f1)); //I'm running this from LINQPad, but this would also work in a console application.
}

public class Form1 : Form // Derives from the Form class
{
    private bool isX; // private instance variable to indicate which image is diplayed
    private Image x; // private instance variable storing the x image
    private Image o; // private instance variable storing the o image

    // the picture box this form uses
    private PictureBox p;

    public Form1()
    {
        // load the images from wherever they are stored.
        // I do this at construction time to avoid doing disk IO when clicking
        x = Image.FromFile(@"C:\image\path\x.png");
        o = Image.FromFile(@"C:\image\path\o.png");

        // Initialize the picture box
        p = new PictureBox {
            Name = "p1",
            Size = new Size(100,100),
            Location = new Point(100,100),
            Image = o //Initialize with the o image
        };

        // register the click event handler
        p.Click += this.ClickHandle;

        // set the flag to false, since the o image is what we start with
        this.isX = false;

        // add PictureBox p to the form
        this.Controls.Add(p);
    }

    // handles the click action, registered to the PictureBox.Click event
    private void ClickHandle(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // use the flag to check which image is shown, and display the other image
        if(this.isX) // this might work with your image == check, I didn't test it
        {
            p.Image = this.o;
        }
        else
        {
            p.Image = this.x;
        }
        // set the flag to the opposite of whatever the flag currently is
        this.isX = ! isX;
    }
}
```

[image: o image]

[image: x image]

Answer (score 1):

[image: You can set value of picturebox image, but you cant get it that way.]

You can set value of picturebox image, but you cant get it that way.

U can use global variable out of method and go this way.

```
    int i = 0;

    private void PictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        if (i == 0)
        {
            pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.close;
            i++;
        }                   
            else
        {
            pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.open;
            i--;
        }                               
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this.

```
    private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (pictureBox1.Image!=null&& getSignatureLen( pictureBox1.Image) == getSignatureLen(Properties.Resources.openeye))
        {
            pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.closeeye;
        }
        else
        {
            pictureBox1.Image = PProperties.Resources.openeye;
        }
    }

    public long  getSignatureLen(Image img)
    {
        using (System.IO.MemoryStream mStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
        {
            img.Save(mStream, img.RawFormat);
            return mStream.Length;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can save the value in the un-used Tag property, of the PictureBox object.

```
pictureBox1.Tag = 1; //Set it to whatever

if (pictureBox1.Tag == "1") { } //Do your check
```